# Как удалить столбцы с типом данных object?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, объекты

У меня есть df в котором 149 столбцов. Мне нужно удалить из него поля с типом данных object.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

вот пример df:

```
Sher = [None, None, None] - object
Hlop = [0.1, 0.7, None] - float
ID = [B0123 05, P0154 95, 04520 00] - object
```

только поля Sher и ID нужно удалить

Спасибо!

Comment: `df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])`

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо! ваш вариант подошёл для решения проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `select_dtypes`

```
df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
```